# Codeigniter Controller, Config variables after upgrade

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am in the process of upgrading CI from 1.x to 3.x 
From my `application/controller/home.php` which has a class:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('app_controller');
  }
...
```

And inside `application/libraries/App_Controller.php`

```
class App_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $config_app = $this->config->load('Application');
...
```

From `application/config/Application.php` I am defining variables:

```
$config['env']          = 'dev';
$config['https']        = '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['js']           = '/ui/js/';
```

But this returns an error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'CI_App_controller' not found

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\system\core\Common.php
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this error and why `App_Controller` is not found.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your libraries shouldn't extend to CI_controller.

What you want to do in that case is move your App_controller into application/core/App_controller.php.

Then go to your application/config/config.php and change your $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; to $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'App_';

Finally your Home controller should extend to App_controller instead like so:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Home extends App_Controller {
      function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('app_controller');
      }
    }
```