# Codeigniter 3.x call to undefined method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error when trying to access a method inside `libraries/View.php` from `core/App_controller.php`. `linkJS()` will set markup for view output.
Why is this method undefined and how can I overcome this?

My folder structure

application/core/App_controller.php

```
function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();

  $this->view = $this->load->library('view');

  $this->set_vars();
}

function set_vars(){
  $this->view->linkJS($this->js.'application.js');
}
```

application/libraries/View.php

```
public function linkJS($src, $var = 'view_js') {

  if (!isset($this->vars[$var])) {
    $this->vars[$var] = {$var};
  }
  // more code ...
}
```

From `views/shell.php` I would like to ouput `echo $view_js;`

error:

> Type: Error
>       Message: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::linkJS()
>       Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\application\core\App_Controller.php

Comment: @RangkaKacang how would i do that?

Comment: @RangkaKacang i restructured from a previous post and got this far.

Comment: from previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116234/codeigniter-controller-config-variables-after-upgrade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179407/discussion-between-rangka-kacang-and-weber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat discussion,

The error message simply means it couldn't find `linkJS()` method/function.

It requires a special loader `MY_Loader.php` or subclass_prefix of your choice `XXX_Loader.php`, which contains that missing method your error is complaining about `Call to undefined method CI_Loader:linkJS()` and needs to be located in `application/core/XXX_Loader.php`

Also, make sure the controller class file naming is [Ucfirst-like manner](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming).

In OP's situation, moving the `linkJS()` function from `View.php` to that special loader, `class App_Loader extends CI_Loader { ... }` does the trick.